# Find most recently added file into SharePoint online library

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

My requirement is to search for a file in my entire SharePoint Online (SPO) using Graph apis. I have my query something like this which I use in MS Graph Explorer:

https://'my domain'.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?Querytext='res1a2b3c4d5e'

Basically above query is to search for all the documents having title/name as 'res1a2b3c4d5e'. This works fine if I search for any existing document. If I try to search for any document which was created/uploaded just before making above call I wont get the result.

If I search for the same after couple of minutes, then the request succeeds. Where as when I try the same on my customers site where it has millions of documents. It nearly takes around 20+ hours before I can do a successful search

So does graph api work on any SPO cache?

How can I search for newly added file without having to wait for 20+ hours?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The search results will be available only after the search content is crawled and available in search index. While you can control the crawl schedule in SharePoint On-Premise, you cannot do so in SharePoint online. Crawling frequency in SharePoint online is managed by Microsoft.

[More Details](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/sharepoint-online-search-service-description.aspx)